# picasso image loading in adapter with Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, picasso

I tried a lot of different examples and read many stack overflow answers and questions, but now I'm lost... This is my normal setup of my ArrayAdapter to fill a listview

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {

protected Context mContext;
protected List<ParseObject> mMessages;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> messages) {
    super(context, R.layout.chat_item, messages);
    mContext = context;
    mMessages = messages;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.userImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        holder.chatImageView = (ParseImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.chatText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
        holder.usernameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.whenLabel);
        holder.whenLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameLabel);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    ParseObject message = mMessages.get(position);
```

INSERT ANSWER

```
    if (message.getParseFile("image") != null) {

        holder.chatImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String chatImageFile = message.getParseFile("image").getUrl();

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(chatImageFile)
                .into(holder.chatImageView);

    } else {

        holder.chatImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

END ANSWER

```
    holder.userImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_picture);
    //holder.chatImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_picture);
    holder.chatText.setText(message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_CHAT_TEXT));
    //holder.usernameLabel.setText(message.getParseUser(ParseConstants.KEY_FROM_USER));
    holder.whenLabel.setText(message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT));




    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    ImageView userImageView;
    ParseImageView chatImageView;
    TextView chatText;
    TextView usernameLabel;
    TextView whenLabel;

}
```

}

Now the problem is I don't know how to implement picasso image loader into this, where to put the Picasso loader and how I get the ParseFile chatImageView...

can someone get me back on track ;-)

Comment: Use Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.YourImage).into(holder.YourImageView);

Comment: the problem is what is `load(R.drawable.YourImage)` in this code, can't figure out where I get this from...

Comment: load method you can put a string url to image, a drawable, or file :) and R.drawable. YourImage is an image you put in the drawable folder in the res directory.

Comment: Fixed! `//load chat image
        if (message.getParseFile("image") != null) {

            holder.chatImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String chatImageFile = message.getParseFile("image").getUrl();

            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(chatImageFile)
                    .into(holder.chatImageView);

        } else {

            holder.chatImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }`